# Three numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$ are chosen at random from the interval $[0, 10]$. What is the probability that $x ≤ y ≤ z$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Three numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$ are chosen at random from the interval $[0, 10]$. What is
> the probability that $x \leq y \leq z$?

The given answer is $1/6$ , it counts all permutation of $x,y,z$ such as $x \leq y \leq z$, $x \leq z \leq y$, $y \leq x \leq z$ etc.

My question is that why didn't we count the situations such as $x<y<z$ ? Why did we count only "less than or equal to" signs ? What is more , what is the probability of $x \leq y< z$?

Comment: I think those situations are irrelevant to the question at hand though. The question states probability that $x\leq y \leq z$.

Comment: Maybe it's because $P(x\le y\le z)=P(x\lt y\lt z)$ since the probability of any two of the numbers being equal is zero?

Comment: Agree with @bof. $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$ so the probability of $x=y$, $y=z$, or $x=z$ is just $0$.

Comment: The other comments are surely correct according to the intention of the question. However, as stated the question is impossible to answer because it does not specify the distribution from which $x,y,z$ are chosen. Presumably they are meant to be independently chosen uniformly from $[0,10]$.

Comment: Doesn't even have to be uniform. Independently and all from the same distribution should be enough. But it should absolutely have been specified.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck I think there might be a problem if the distribution contains atoms.  For example, if $\mathbb{P}(x = 0) \approx 1$ and $x,y,z$ are chosen independently from the same distribution, we would have $\mathbb{P}(x \le y \le z) \ge \mathbb{P}(x=y=z=0) \approx 1.$  I  agree that independently and all from the same distribution satisfying $\mathbb{P}(x=c)=0$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is enough, though.

Comment: @user6247850 Oh yes, good point. We do need the fact that it makes no difference whether we have less-than or less-or-equal-to signs (in particular since this was the original point of the question).